# dynamically added template using $http controller not working in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have the following controller

```
app.controller('PageController', ['$scope', '$http', 'PageService', '$sce', function($scope, $http, PageService, $sce) {

////////changetab is ng-click event
$scope.changetab = function(url) {
        PageService.http.get(app.genurl(url)).success(function(data) {
            $scope.datas = $sce.trustAsHtml(data);
        })
    }

}])
```

ng-bind-html will load the dynamic templates which holds another controller

```
<div ng-controller="PageController">
<div ng-bind-html="datas"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the controller for dynamic template

```
app.controller('AboutController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.disname = 'Relicset';
}])
```

Here is the html template loaded dynamically

```
<div ng-controller="AboutController">
    {{ disname }}
</div>
```

Problem is in aboutcontroller disname is not printing as Relicset instead showing {{ disname }} How to handle such case.

Comment: Why don't you use `ng-include`

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the html you loaded has to be compiled by angular, in this case I think the best solution should be to do a directive and use the compile in your link function.

here is a little example

```
app.diractive('tabs', function (PageService, $sce, $compile) {
    return {
         restrict: 'E',
         replace: true,
         template: '<div>{{datas}}</div>', //option 1, use template (it is compiled by angular)
         link: function (scope, element) {                 
             PageService.http.get(app.genurl(url)).success(function(data) {
                  scope.datas = $sce.trustAsHtml(data);
                  //this is another option, compile the recived data
                  //angular.element(element).html($compile(data)(scope))
             })
         }
    };
});
```

this example will guide you. it wont work 100% maybe you have to add a controller, and a scope check this link for more info https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive